# XPATH select multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml file:

```
<a ida="1">
    <b>data</b>
    <c idc="1">
        <d>data</d>
        <e ide="1">
            <f>data</f>
        </e>
        <e ide="2">
            <f>data</f>
        </e>
    </c>
</a>

<a ida="2">
    <b>data</b>
    <c idc="2">
        <d>data</d>
        <e ide="3">
            <f>data</f>
        </e>
        <e ide="4">
            <f>data</f>
        </e>
    </c>
</a>
```

I want to retrieve via XPATH the b element as well as all the e childs of c with their f element.

To do something like this with XQUERY:

```
xquery version "3.0";
for $x in doc("file.xml")//a//c//e
order by $x//f ascending
return <res>{$x/../../b, $x//f}</res>
```

In XPATH i can only select one element:

```
doc("askhsh.xml")//a//c//e//f
```

Comment: From your comments in the answers below, you want an XPath solution instead of XQuery right? What version of XPath do you use?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that but i have the latest version of baseX if that helps.

Comment: What about the first question, is it XQuery or XPath solution that you're after? (because BaseX is mainly used with XQuery, not just XPath)

Comment: i am looking for a xpath only solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is en xPath you are looking for:

```
//a/b | //a/c/e
```

Comment: This prints all the b's and then all the e's... is it possible to display all the b's with the c's after? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it is not very clear what result you want from the query. My best guess is this

```
xquery version "3.0";
for $x in doc("so.xml")//a
  let $b := $x/b
  let $fs := $x//f
  let $es := 
    for $f in $fs          
    order by $f ascending
    return $f/..
return <res>{($b,$es)}</res>
```

Comment: the xquery i posted works fine, the xpath is the issue.

Comment: I have just edited the answer, can you see if this works?

Comment: Thank you for your time. My problem is in the xpath and not in the xquery code.

Comment: I want to help but can you provide exactly the result you want to have? comment something like:  `<res><b>data</b><c><e ide="1"><f>adata</f><f>bdata</f></e></c></res>`
Do you only want to change the last line xpath?

Comment: i need something like <res><b>data></b><f>data</f></res>